# How to force an implementation for an API Java

Tags: java, interface, abstract, api-design

We had this question on API design. and its drilling a hole in my head and can't figure this one out.

say for example I have an interface with one method, to read a file but you need some sort of credentials passed, so the object here could be any pojo really.

```
public interface Reader(){
     public void read(String identifier, Object credentials);
}
```

The question was how do I force a developer if they extend this to implement the credentials, to make sure that it is valid credentials and not just bypass it. Here are my suggested solutions:

```
public boolean authenticate(Object credentials);
```

OR, it could be something like this

```
 public Object authenticate(Object credentials);
```

I also tried this way, so it gives a default authentication

```
public interface Auth {
    default boolean authenticate() {
        //do real authentication
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the response I would pass to the `Reader` interface, they came back to me saying the developer could always ignore this as well, and say just `return true`. and that all of this was wrong.

They hinted that the answer had to do with `Abstract classes`, but I was thinking if it was an abstract class, wouldn't it mean that if I had extended wouldn't mean I could still override this method? and say `return true` still?

```
abstract class Auth {
    public boolean authenticate(Object o) {
        //some real authentication
        return boolean ;
    }
}
//developer implementation
class extends AuthImpl extends Auth{
        public boolean authenticate(Object o){
            return true;
        }
}
```

It was a panel discussion, and they were all in agreement that there is a way so that the developer couldn't do just return true with abstracts. What am I missing here? How do I enforce that the developer does implement actual authentication properly rather than just returning true? please help can't seem to figure this one out

Comment: If authentification is fully implemented by developer, who uses your API, then I don't think it is possible to ensure that he/she would implement 'real authentification' and not just return true.

Comment: they were quite sure there is a way, and I just can't figure it out :/

Comment: Firstly, this is a bad architecture. At least you need to have a class with `boolean final authentificate(Object credentialProvidedByUser)` method where you, as an API programer, implement real authentification and developer, who uses your API, provide just credentials.

Comment: again, i can still say return true when I implement your method, thus bypassing the authentication?

Comment: No, you, as an API user, cannot overide `final` method.

Comment: yes I know i cannot override a final method, but the question was they should override the method but they shouldn't just do return true. and i argued how do i force a developer to not just do return true, if im the one implementing, but apparently there is a way.

Comment: You can't force a developer to implement a method in a certain way *in code*. You can put a gun to his head and that will work, but you can't write code that would prevent the developer from working around that code.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking, so this question is blowing my mind.

Comment: Make Reader an abstract class instead of an interface.  Require credentials in the constructor.  Throw if they're not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving it some thought and based on all the answers here, I think this is what they meant. Thanks to @Kayaman's answer for leading to the right direction.

through `abstract` this is the way, since you have imposed that `Reader` have 1 parameter `constructor` he cannot instantiate it, and he is forced to put a `super` call in his implementation.

```
abstract class Reader {
    protected Object authentication;
    ReaderImpl(Object authentication) throws Exception{
        if(null == authentication){
            throw new Exception();
        }else{
            this.authentication = authentication;
        }
    }
    public void reader(String x, Object authentication) {
        System.out.println("Reader Implemented");
    }

}

class DevReader extends Reader{
    public DevReader(Object authentication) throws Exception{
        super(authentication);
    }
    @Override
    public void reader(String x, Object authentication) {
        System.out.println("Dev Implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get rid of the Reader interface.  If you have a method that takes a Reader, then someone can implement it without using ReaderImpl at all.  Methods that require authenticating readers need to take ReaderImpl parameters instead...  and you should just call ReaderImpl Reader.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force an implementation, you'll have to have a class, abstract or not. Of course `authenticate` would be made `final` so it can't be overridden (of course nothing stops you from making it non-final if you're the developer, so it becomes a bit academic on how that would really ensure safety).

One way would be to just take the Reader implementation from the outside as a parameter, so the developer is free to implement the reading, but the rest of the system always uses `AuthReader` everywhere (this creates a direct dependency to the authentication which is a lot harder to bypass as it would require changing all all places that use it). This allows flexibility in reading, but security in the authentication.

Something like this

```
public final class AuthReader implements Reader {
    private Reader reader;
    private Object credentials;
    public AuthReader(Reader reader, Object credentials) {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.credentials = Objects.requireNonNull(credentials);
    }

    private boolean isAuthenticated() {
        ... // authenticate credentials
    }

    public String readString() {
        if(!isAuthenticated())
            throw new SecurityException();
        return reader.readString();
    }
}
```

Comment: plus one for decorator pattern :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think they wanted to see the following contractual pattern:

```
public abstract class Reader(){

     // Requirement to implement:
     protected abstract void authenticate(Object credentials);

     // Requirement to implement:
     protected abstract void actuallyRead(BufferedReader in, String identifier,
         Object credentials) throws IOException;

     //  Service provided:
     public final void read(String identifier, Object credentials) {
         ... using authenticate and actuallyRead ...
     }
}
```

The *client developers* simply have an API of a `read` function. But the *implementor* must provide functionality (`authenticate, actuallyRead`). That is used as the *API creator* specifies.

Notice that `actuallyRead` can be passed (provide) and return (require) extra information.

Comment: Hi Joop this sounds close to what they meant, but they can still extend this Reader and say return true for the authenticate method, the emphasis revolved around saying the developer couldn't just do return true on authenticate method though

Comment: The idea is to call an existing non-dummy `authenticate` in the public final method. You could make the method `authenticate` private final, if you knew how to deal with credentials. Maybe some separate interface Credentials, but honestly, the problem stated in the question then becomes very convoluted. In a real world production environment one would ask clarification.

Answer (score 0):

### Ensure credentials at Compile-Time

Lets assume you only allow to instanticate a instance of Authorized with valid credentials.

Assuming you have this:

```
public final class Authorized {
    private final Object credentials;

    public abstract class Reader {
    }

    public Authorized(Object credentials) {
        if (credentials == null) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(credentials, "Missing credentials");
        }
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }
}
```

This way you are  able to extend from Reader but you are not able to instanticate a superclass from Reader **without** having a instance of `Authorized`.

Example:

```
public class MyReader extends Authorized.Reader {
    public MyReader() {
           // YOU MUST CALL .super() HERE ON A 
           // INSTANCE OF Authroized or you can not compile.
    }
}
```

1. Inside the default constructor of MyReader you must use a instance of Authroized, in example `new Authorized("").super()`.
2. You can not inherit `Authroized` to rewrite the constructor.
3. You can not create instances of MyReader without a instance of `Authroized`.